# can't install keras on ubuntu 18

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to install keras using pip command but I get this error

```
Collecting tensorflow>=2.2.0 (from keras)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow>=2.2.0 (from keras) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)

No matching distribution found for tensorflow>=2.2.0 (from keras)
```

I am installing it using
`sudo pip3 install keras`
and I have already installed tensorflow using `sudo pip3 install tensorflow`

how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras has been a part of tensorflow since 2.0. Check out the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model).

If you have `tensorflow>=2.0` installed already, all you have to do is import `keras`-

```py
from tensorflow import keras
```

That's it!

Edit: You'll have to change your import patterns a bit, for example, to import `load_model` from `keras.models` - you need to do

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

The reason you cannot use

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model
```

is simply because `python`'s import system relies on *real* packages.

This is very well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830407/10305477)

> The Python import system just doesn't work that way. When you do from foo import bar, foo has to be a "real", fully-qualified package or module name (or a relative one using dots). That is, it has to be something that you could use in a plain import foo. It can't just be a module object you have lying around.

You can also find this information in the [`import` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

Comment: I tried to put it before this from ```keras.models import load_model``` but I got the same error

Comment: @MoatazBeheta you cannot use the already imported `keras` as a module to import things from, I edited my answer to explain

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that Tensorflow 2 has Keras integrated in it. Try running a test code that uses Keras and see if it's working.

Comment: I got this error:
```Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Recording-and-Prediction.py", line 4, in <module>

    from keras.models import load_model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras' 
```